# cannot copy to non-directory: Docker compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using `docker-compose build` to build the image but I am always getting below error for the command `ADD . /.` in my `Dockerfile.it`

```
  => ERROR [sample/test-example:latest 8/8] ADD . /.
                                                                                                                             
  ------
  > [sample/test-example:latest 8/8] ADD . /.
  ------
  failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = cannot copy to non-directory: /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ul1wueihd47ieq2tzmd2rwopq/merged/lib
```

I am using below versions

Docker Desktop version : 4.5.0

Docker Engine : 20

MacOS

Answer (score -1):

ADD copies files, folders, or remote URLs from source to the dest path in the image's filesystem.

`ADD source dest`

*Eg:*

`ADD hello.txt /absolute/path`

`ADD hello.txt relative/to/workdir`

In your case,

`ADD . /.` does not mention any valid destination. `/.` is a root path. If you want to copy to the current work directory use `ADD . ./` or to any other folder use `ADD . <path to folder>`.

*Note*: When adding multiple source files or directories, there must be a / at the end of the destination directory.

Comment: Thank you for response. I tried with `ADD . ./` but same error.

Comment: Please paste your Dockerfile here. So that we can help you